# Will the terraform fail if the data does not exist?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

Will the terraform fail if a user in the data does not exist?
I need to specify a user in the nonproduction environment by the data block:

```
data "aws_iam_user" "labUser" {
  user_name = "gitlab_user"
}
```

Then I use this user in giving the user permissions:

```
resource "aws_iam_role" "ApiAccessRole_abc" {
 name = "${var.stack}-ApiAccessRole_abc"
 tags = "${var.tags}"
 assume_role_policy = <<EOF
{
 "Version": "2019-11-29",
 "Statement": [
   {
     "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
  "Principal": {
    "AWS": [
    "${aws_iam_user.labUser.arn}"
    ]
  },
  "Effect": "Allow",
  "Sid": ""
 }
 ]
}
EOF
}
```

In the production environment this user does not exist.  Would the terraform break if this user does not exist?  What would be a good approach to use the same terraform in both environments?

Comment: What do you intend to happen if the user doesn't exist? And yes, Terraform will fail if the data source returns zero results.

Comment: Does something prevent you from managing the IAM user directly?

Comment: @MattSchuchardthe terraform will remove the manual settings after run

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In Terraform a `data` block like you showed here is both a mechanism to fetch data and also an assertion by the author (you) that a particular external object is expected to exist in order for this configuration to be applyable.

In your case then, the answer is to ensure that the assertion that the object exists only appears in situations where it should exist. The "big picture" answer to this is to review the [Module Composition](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/modules/develop/composition.html) guide and consider whether this part of your module ought to be decomposed into a separate module if it isn't *always* a part of the module it's embedded in, but I'll also show a smaller solution that uses conditional expressions to get the behavior you wanted without any refactoring:

```
variable "lab_user" {
  type    = string
  default = null
}

data "aws_iam_user" "lab_user" {
  count = length(var.lab_user[*])

  user_name = var.lab_user
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "api_access_role_abc" {
 count = length(data.aws_iam_user.lab_user)

 name = "${var.stack}-ApiAccessRole_abc"
 tags = var.tags
 assume_role_policy = jsonencode({
   Version   = "2019-11-29"
   Statement = [
     {
       Sid    = ""
       Action = "sts:AssumeRole"
       Effect = "Allow"
       Principal = {
         AWS = [data.aws_iam_user.lab_user[count.index].arn]
       }
     },
   ]
 })
}
```

There's a few different things in the above that I want to draw attention to:

- I made the lab username an optional variable rather than a hard-coded value. You can than change the behavior between your environments by assigning a different value to that `lab_user` variable, or leaving it unset altogether for environments that don't need a "lab user".
- In the `data "aws_iam_user"` I set count to `length(var.lab_user[*])`. The `[*]` operator here is asking Terraform to translate the possibly-null string variable `var.lab_user` into a list of either zero or one elements, and then using the length of that list to decide how many `aws_iam_user` queries to make. If `var.lab_user` is `null` then the length will be zero and so no queries will be made.
- Finally, I set the `count` for the `aws_iam_role` resource to match the length of the `aws_iam_user` data result, so that in any situation where there's one user expected there will also be one role created.

If you reflect on the Module Composition guide and conclude that this lab user ought to be a separate concern in a separate module then you'd be able to remove this conditional complexity from the "gitlab user" module itself and instead have the calling module either call that module or not depending on whether such a user is needed for that environment. The effect would be the same, but the decision would be happening in a different part of the configuration and thus it would achieve a different separation of concerns. Which separation of concerns is most appropriate for your system is, in the end, a tradeoff you'll need to make for yourself based on your knowledge of the system and how you expect it might evolve in future.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested in the comments it will fail.

One approach that I can suggest is to supply the username as a var that you pass externally from a file [dev.tfvars and prod.tfvars](https://www.terraform.io/docs/cli/commands/apply.html) and run terraform with:

```
terraform apply --var-file example.tfvars
```

Then in your data resource you can have a count or for_each to check whether the var has been populated or not (if var has not been passed, you can skip the data interpolation)

```
  count = var.enable_gitlab_user ? 1 : 0
```

The AWS direct approach would be to switch from IAM user in the Principal to tag-based Condition or even Role chaining. You can take a [look at this AWS blog post for some ideas](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-use-trust-policies-with-iam-roles/). There are examples for both cases.

Answer (score 0):

Referencing the non-existent data source will cause terraform to fail.  Here's my preferred approach to this, as I've recently come across the same issue.

I rely on an [aws_iam_roles](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/iam_users) data source, which allows you to search for existing IAM roles based on a regex match on the role name or a path prefix.  In my particular use-case I did this for an IAM role, but it should work the same way for IAM users with the [aws_iam_users](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/iam_roles) data source.

The data sources have a 'name' attribute which is a set of matched IAM roles, which you can then compare against your intended role/user and conditionally create the resource.

```
data "aws_iam_users" "exists" {
  name_regex = "^gitlab_user"
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "api_access_role_abc" {
 count = contains(aws_iam_users.exists.names, 'gitlab_user') ? 1 : 0
 ...etc
}
```

P.S. I'm currently using Terraform v1.0.11